# WPF MouseLeftButtonUp Not Firing

Tags: wpf, events, button, mouseleftbuttonup

When I use the `MouseUp` event, I can get it to fire with a mouse right-click. But `MouseLeftButtonUp` won't fire with either click!

```xml
<Button MouseLeftButtonUp="btnNewConfig_MouseUp"  Name="btnNewConfig">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="Icons\new.ico" Height="24" Width="24" Margin="5"/>
        <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Center">New</TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

I know this is most likely something simple. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Since the question was about a button and only one event was hooked I want to say that you might just want its Click event not MouseLeftButtonUp or MouseLeftButtonDown. Unless you are doing something exotic like a different behavior depending on how long the user holds the button down.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Looks like `Button` control is eating up that event Since `Button.Click` is actually a combination of `LeftButtonDown` event and `LeftButtonUp` event.

But you can subscribe to the tunneled event **`PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp`** on the `Button` instead of `LeftButtonUp`.

Answer (score 8):

Subscribing to a tunneled event instead of a bubble one has some pretty messy side effects which I will explain later.

Here is a better solution as in it keeps your bubble intact. :)

```
btnNewConfig.AddHandler(MouseLeftButtonUpEvent, 
                        new RoutedEventHandler(btnNewConfig_MouseUp), 
                        true);
```

You will have to declare your event handler with `RoutedEventArgs` instead of `MouseButtonEventArgs` but you can just cast it back to `MouseButtonEventArgs` inside.

```
void btnNewConfig_MouseUp(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MouseButtonEventArgs args = e as MouseButtonEventArgs;
    // ...
}
```

Note the last argument in `AddHandler` - making it true causes your event to fire even if previous handler set `e.Handled = true;`

**Now about `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp`:**

Tunneling events fire for parents before children. Bubbling - the opposite.
If you have many event handlers involved you should really stick to all bubbling or all tunneling or else the more event handlers you add the more confusing it gets - adding one new event handler may cause you to revisit all the other ones in the application.

Most people find bubbling model a much more natural one.
This is why the accepted answer is problematic.

Comment: P.S. e.Handled is not be the only reason your event might not be fired. 
Another possibility is something upstream from you called Mouse.Capture.

Comment: "you should really stick to all bubbling or all tunneling" that's my case

Answer (score 4):

`Button` is using the Mouse[Left/Right]Button[Up/Down] events (and marking them as `Handled`) for its `Button.Click` events.

As [Jobi said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/318304/10927863), you can use the `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` event, but I want to suggest that you create your own button template and modify its behavior. (i.e. not mark the `MouseLeftButtonUp` as `Handled = true`) or simply use something else than a `Button` as your parent container (depends on what you really need it for).