# How to use mouseDown and mouseUp on <button/>

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mouseevent, mediaelement

I have a button declared in XAML which has MouseDown and MouseUp attributes that both call a specified method...

```
<Button x:Name="btnBackward" Content="Backward"
        MouseDown="btnBackward_MouseDown" 
        MouseUp="btnBackward_MouseReleased" Width="50" Height="25" 
        Margin="65,400,377,45"/>
```

However, the method btnBackward_MouseReleased is never called.

```
private void btnBackward_MouseReleased(object sender, 
                                       System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("mousereleased");
    this.isRewinding = false;
}
```

What am-I missing ?

Comment: Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/318288/wpf-mouseleftbuttonup-not-firing

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use `Preview events` here. So, instead of `MouseDown` and `MouseUp`, hook to `PreviewMouseDown` and `PreviewMouseUp`.

```
<Button x:Name="btnBackward" Content="Backward"
        PreviewMouseDown="btnBackward_MouseDown" 
        PreviewMouseUp="btnBackward_MouseReleased"/>
```

Reason form [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752279.aspx) -

> Button suppresses MouseLeftButtonDown and MouseLeftButtonDown
>   bubbling events raised by the Button or its composite elements in
>   favor of capturing the mouse and raising a Click event that is always
>   raised by the Button itself. The event and its data still continue
>   along the route, but because the Button marks the event data as
>   Handled, only handlers for the event that specifically indicated they
>   should act in the handledEventsToo case are invoked. If other elements
>   towards the root of your application still wanted an opportunity to
>   handle a control-suppressed event, one alternative is to attach
>   handlers in code with handledEventsToo specified as true. But often a
>   simpler technique is to change the routing direction you handle to be
>   the Preview equivalent of an input event. **For instance, if a control
>   suppresses MouseLeftButtonDown, try attaching a handler for
>   PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown instead**.

However, if you right click on your button `MouseUp` and `MouseDown` events will work perfectly since click doesn't eat up the event in that case and they are properly bubbled up.