# MouseUp event doesnt work on left click

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mouseup

I am making a GUI using Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF). When I mouse click a button (left or right), I want a message box shown. So far I have managed to make an example from tutorials, but it only works when I *right-click*, and **not** when I *left-click* the button. I cannot see anything in my code, which should prevent left-click from working, so I hope you can help me.

**XAML code**

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="72">
        Hello, WPF!
    </TextBlock>

    <!-- This button shuld activate the even MyButton_MouseUp -->
    <Button Margin="200,250,200,20" Name="MyButton"  MouseUp="MyButton_MouseUp">
        Test
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

**C# code**

```
// This only works on right-click
private void MyButton_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Hello world!");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subscribe to the [`PreviewMouseUp`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mouse.previewmouseup(v=vs.110).aspx)'s *Tunneled event* instead of `MouseUp`:

```
<Button Margin="200,250,200,20" Name="MyButton"  PreviewMouseUp="MyButton_MouseUp" />
```

The `PreviewMouseUp`'s *Routing strategy* is **Tunneling**, i.e it will go down of the `VisualTree` hierarchy, and so the [Tunnel events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806(v=vs.110).aspx) are triggered before the [Bubble events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. Any chance you can also explain why? :-)

Comment: @Noceo See my updated answer and also have a look at the MSDN links that I included.

Comment: Cool. I still don't get why it worked on right click though, but at least now I know that there are different event types. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to S. Akbari's post, this one is worth reading in order to understand why *right-click* works, and *left-click* does not...

[How to use mouseDown and mouseUp on <button/>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364366/how-to-use-mousedown-and-mouseup-on-button)