# WPF MouseUp EventTrigger on Button doesn't set BorderBrush & BorderThickness

Tags: wpf, triggers, mouseup, wpf-animation, coloranimation

I have a reset button - the desired behaviour is to increase in size on mouseover and, once clicked, have a border around it.

The IsMouseOver trigger works, but I can't get the MouseUp event trigger to work (once pressed the button does not display a border).

I have tried the following:

1) Adding an event trigger to the control template triggers

2) Adding an event trigger to the style triggers

3) Adding an event trigger to the button triggers

Am I writing the event trigger incorrectly? I've added the code for the three attempts below - hoping I've just missed something obvious and is a quick fix. Thanks!

**1 - Adding an event trigger to the control template triggers**

```
    <Button x:Name="ResetButton"
                    Margin="0,0,20,0"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Command="{Binding Path=DoClearCmd}"
                    ToolTip="Reset all search criteria.">
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
                      <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                 FontSize="16"
                                 Foreground="White"
                                 Text=" Reset" />
                       <Image Width="16"
                              Height="16"
                              Margin="2,0,0,0"
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                              VerticalAlignment="Center"                                          Source="..\Resources\Delete_16x16.png" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <Button.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                    <Setter Property="dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName" Value="None" />
                                    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
                                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
                                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="25" />
                                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="25" />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                <Border x:Name="Border">
                                                    <ContentPresenter Margin="2"
                                                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                                                </Border>
                                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseUp">
                                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                                            <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Tomato" />
                                                                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" To="2" />
                                                            </Storyboard>
                                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                                    </EventTrigger>
                                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
                                                                                     To="1.05" />
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
                                                                                     To="1.05" />
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
                                                                                     To="1" />
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
                                                                                     To="1" />
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>
                            </Button.Style>
                        </Button>
```

**2 - Adding an event trigger to the style triggers**

```
      <Button x:Name="ResetButton"
                                Margin="0,0,20,0"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Command="{Binding Path=DoClearCmd}"
                                ToolTip="Reset all search criteria.">
                            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           FontSize="16"
                                           Foreground="White"
                                           Text=" Reset" />
                                <Image Width="16"
                                       Height="16"
                                       Margin="2,0,0,0"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Source="..\Resources\Delete_16x16.png" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <Button.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                    <Setter Property="dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName" Value="None" />
                                    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
                                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
                                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="25" />
                                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="25" />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                <Border x:Name="Border">
                                                    <ContentPresenter Margin="2"
                                                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                                                </Border>
                                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                                                      
                                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
                                                                                     To="1.05" />
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
                                                                                     To="1.05" />
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
                                                                                     To="1" />
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
                                                                                     To="1" />
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Style.Triggers>
                                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseUp">
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                                    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Tomato" />
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" To="2" />
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </EventTrigger>
                                    </Style.Triggers>
                                </Style>                                    
                            </Button.Style>
                        </Button>
```

**3 - Adding an event trigger to the button triggers**

```
    <Button x:Name="ResetButton"
                                Margin="0,0,20,0"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Command="{Binding Path=DoClearCmd}"
                                ToolTip="Reset all search criteria.">
                            <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           FontSize="16"
                                           Foreground="White"
                                           Text=" Reset" />
                                <Image Width="16"
                                       Height="16"
                                       Margin="2,0,0,0"
                                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                       Source="..\Resources\Delete_16x16.png" />
                            </StackPanel>
                            <Button.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                    <Setter Property="dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName" Value="None" />
                                    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
                                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
                                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="25" />
                                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="25" />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                                    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                <Border x:Name="Border">
                                                    <ContentPresenter Margin="2"
                                                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                                      RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                                                </Border>
                                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                                                      
                                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
                                                                                     To="1.05" />
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
                                                                                     To="1.05" />
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                                <Storyboard>
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
                                                                                     To="1" />
                                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
                                                                                     To="1" />
                                                                </Storyboard>
                                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                                                    </Trigger>
                                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                            </ControlTemplate>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Style>                                    
                            </Button.Style>
                            <Button.Triggers>
                                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.MouseUp">
                                    <BeginStoryboard>
                                        <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ResetButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Tomato" />
                                            <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ResetButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" To="2" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </EventTrigger>
                            </Button.Triggers>
                        </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. To animate Thickness, you have to use ThicknessAnimation
2. Button does not fire **MouseLeftButtonUp** routed event. Workaround is to use **PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp** event. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318288/wpf-mouseleftbuttonup-not-firing)
3. You have to bind your "Border" element properties BorderBrush and BorderThickness to your template.

For your first case:

```
        <Button>
            <Button.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Setter Property="dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName" Value="None" />
                    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true" />
                    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
                    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
                    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="25" />
                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="25" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="1" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Template">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                <Border x:Name="Border"
                                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}">
                                    <ContentPresenter Margin="2"
                                                                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                                                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                                                  RecognizesAccessKey="True" />
                                </Border>
                                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseUp">
                                        <BeginStoryboard>
                                            <Storyboard Duration="0:0:2" AutoReverse="True" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.BorderBrush).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" To="Tomato" />
                                                <ThicknessAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderThickness" To="4" />
                                            </Storyboard>
                                        </BeginStoryboard>
                                    </EventTrigger>
                                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                        <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
                                                                                 To="1.05" />
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
                                                                                 To="1.05" />
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </Trigger.EnterActions>
                                        <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                                <Storyboard>
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
                                                                                 To="1" />
                                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.2"
                                                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
                                                                                 To="1" />
                                                </Storyboard>
                                            </BeginStoryboard>
                                        </Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    </Trigger>
                                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </Button.Style>
        </Button>
```

**NOTE** that MouseUp is firing only for Right mouse button up

Hope, it helps

Comment: Thanks, this didn't work either - we use a 3rd party UI framework that may be doing something behind the scenes. I've tried a million different combos to no avail.

Comment: So why didn't you write about it in your question??

Comment: because I'd taken away the theme for this button, as show in my xaml:  <Setter Property="dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName" Value="None" /> I don't know if it is changing anything, it's just a hunch seeing as nothing is working.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the 3rd party framework.  Please see my answer for the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why these methods don't work is because the MouseUp event is consumed by the button, and never gets to your handler.  This can be demonstrated by a right click (which isn't consumed) instead of a left click, and your above code will work (I only tested the first sample).

To solve this you can use use the `PreviewMouseUp` event instead.  This worked for me in your first sample.