# wpf Setting mouse handler for dynamic button

Tags: c#, wpf

I am attempting to learn c# and wpf.  I have a segment of code that works in that it shows the controls correctly.  I also attempt to create a mouse button handler and when I debug it, the handler is never called.  The buttons are nested within a couple of StackPanels, that can't seem to be the problem?

```
        StackPanel tabPanel = new StackPanel();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        {
            StackPanel micPanel = new StackPanel();
            micPanel.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

            //  Add the Calibration Button
            Button micButton = new Button();
            micButton.Height = 25;
            micButton.Name = string.Format("Mic{0}", i);
            micButton.Content = string.Format("Mic{0}", ((20 * index) + i));
            micButton.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(mic_MouseLeftButtonUp);
            micPanel.Children.Add(micButton);

            // Add the calibrated Value
            Label micLabel = new Label();
            micLabel.Height = 25;
            micLabel.Content = string.Format("Value: {0}", ((20 * index) + i));
            micPanel.Children.Add(micLabel);

            tabPanel.Children.Add(micPanel);
        }
        tab.Content = tabPanel;
```

The handler looks like this:

```
    private void mic_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Button but = sender as Button;
    }
```

I set a breakpoint and it never calls the handler?

Answer (score 0):

This is typical: use the [preview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1460266/6996876) event handler to make sure it is raised first in the tree view.

```
micButton.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(mic_MouseLeftButtonUp);
```

Comment: Is this because some other device is consuming the click and it never gets to my handler?  Is this something I should always use?  Or is it just because of the container it is in?

Comment: @Sting There is online documentation available, that explains this in detail.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you handle the `Click` event of the Button?

```
micButton.Click += new ClickEventHandler(mic_Click);
...

private void mic_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button but = sender as Button;
}
```

Certain controls do "swallow" certain events but the `Button` control doesn't raise any `MouseButtonUp` event. It raises a `Click` event. The `Click` event is actually a combination of the `LeftButtonDown` and `LeftButtonUp` event:

[WPF MouseLeftButtonUp Not Firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318288/wpf-mouseleftbuttonup-not-firing)

You can read more about routed events and how they work in the documentation on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806%28v=vs.110%29.aspx