# What EventName values can be used for FocusMoment?

Tags: catel

I have the following test code, based on the example in [Catel-LATEST](https://catelproject.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/CTL/pages/1409074/Focus):

```
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBox Name="testTarget" Text="{Binding FirstName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, FallbackValue='Test Target'}" Background="Aquamarine">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <catel:Focus FocusMoment="Event" Source="{Binding ElementName=mouseEnter}" EventName="MouseEnter" FocusDelay="0" />
                <catel:Focus FocusMoment="Event" Source="{Binding ElementName=mouseLeftButtonUp}" EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp" FocusDelay="0"/>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </TextBox>
        <TextBox Name="mouseEnter" Text="Mouse Enter"/>
        <TextBox Name="mouseLeftButtonUp" Text="Left Button Up"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

I can click on `mouseEnter` and then move the mouse away and back, and focus moves to `testTarget`, as desired. But when I left-click on `mouseLeftButtonUp`, it stays on that control. Am I doing something wrong? Or perhaps there's a restricted list of `EventName` values that `FocusMoment` responds to?

Answer (score 0):

Looks good. If you believe you found a bug, please create an official ticket on the Catel repository **with a repro**.

Comment: "with a repo"? Meaning, I suppose, code to reproduce it? If so, I could provide the XAML of the window, or I could attach the whole solution. What are you looking for?

Comment: Oh, wait. You said "repro" as in reproduce. OK, I'll go ahead and submit.

Comment: When I directly subscribe to the events (as in regular event handlers), the events are not fired either, so that's the core of the issue. For more information, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318288/wpf-mouseleftbuttonup-not-firing. 

The solution is to use PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp (which is always invoked, no matter whether it's handled or not).